# StringWithFormat "%.2ld" objc to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipickerview, stringwithformat

I have an 'pickerView' object in a swift project.
I do understand the code in Objective-c but I'm not sure how to implement it in Swift.

**The Objc method**

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component)
    {
        case 0://Week
            return 7;
        case 1://Hour
            return 24;
        default://Minutes
            return 60;//or 7;(10 by 10) //or 13;(5 by 5)
    }
}
```

I'm only not sure how to implement the switch statement for the titleForRow function.
So the `stringWithFormat:@"%.2ld",(long)row` is the problem.

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component)
    {
        case 0://Week
            return _dayOfWeek[row];
        case 1://Hour
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2ld",(long)row];
        default://Minutes
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2ld",(long)row];//or ,row*10] //or ,row*5]
    }
}
```

Can any one help me.

Greetings, dax

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can continue to use stringWithFormat, but initializer names get mangled a little bit:

```
return NSString(format: "%.2ld", row)
```

Basically any class method that's named `[{{class}} {{class}}WithXXXX:...]` will be renamed to an initializer as `{{Class}}(XXXX:...)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `var str = NSString(format: "Hello, world %.2ld", 42.12312312313)`

Comment: Note that the OP specifies the value as type `(long)` not a floating point number. The answer code produces: "Hello, world 00" which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. No, I just need an output witch is the int of the return type in the `numberOfRowsInComponent`.